# how to modify sharepoint library file using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

First, I'm just a rookie

I wanna modify a .aspx template and copy to create a new file in the same library, I googled it, but no much showed up

Anybody can help? Either link or code will be very very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You should start with SharePoint Designer, it is a free product from Microsoft.

A rather good introduction movie http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tpwEUA9IGdY, there are so much more on youtube.

Resources

- http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/product/related-technologies/pages/sharepoint-designer.aspx
- http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16573 SharePoint Designer 32-bit
- http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24309 SharePoint Designer 64-bit